# Partial derivative 8

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I have the following derivative:
$$f'(k)=\frac{a(1+bk)}{k^{1-a}(1+abk)^{^{a}}}$$
and have to compute the partial derivative with respect to b, possibly obtaining the following result:

$$\frac{\partial f'(k)}{\partial b}=\frac{ak^{a}(1-a)(1+a+abk)}{(1+abk)^{a+1}}$$

I've tried to do the exercise but I cannot get closer to the desired result than this:

$$\frac{\partial f'{(k)}}{\partial b}=ak^{a}(1+abk)^{-a}\left [ 1-\frac{a(a+abk)}{(1+abk)} \right ]$$

Thank you so much and Happy Christmas! :)

Comment: Use logarithmic differentiation just as I made it in your previous post and factor terms..

Comment: Thank u so much! I will try that way. What is the advantage of log differentiation? It is possible to obtain the same result with normal derivation?

Comment: The advantage is that evrything becomes simpler. For sure, using *normal derivation* will give the same answer (but more tedious).

Comment: In this case since k is now a constant in the first step i have to start with this, right? $$\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{k}{(1+bk)}-\frac{a^{2}k}{(1+abk)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct. It's just a matter of simplifications.
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f'(k)}{\partial b}
& = \frac{ak^{a}(1-a)(1+a+abk)}{(1+abk)^{a+1}}\\
& = \frac{ak^{a}(1+a+abk-a-a^2-a^2bk)}{(1+abk)^{a+1}}\\
& = \frac{ak^{a}(1+abk-a^2-a^2bk)}{(1+abk)^{a+1}}\\
&=\frac{ak^{a}(1+abk)^{-a}(1+abk-a^2-a^2bk)}{(1+abk)}\\
& = ak^{a}(1+abk)^{-a}\left [ 1-\frac{a(a+abk)}{(1+abk)} \right ]
\end{align}